# In a Knockout observable array subscription function, can you determine what elements were added or removed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

Knockout's [Observable Arrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) give you the ability to "subscribe" to changes to the array, [just like any other observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html). The "subscribe" callback function receives one argument, and it's the *new* value of the array. Here's an example (and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbeall/Vf8RK/1/)):

```
var oa = ko.observableArray(['some','initial','data']);

oa.subscribe(function(newValue){
    console.log("Array was updated! Now it's:");
    console.log(newValue);
    // But which item was added?
});

oa.push("more data!");
setTimeout(function(){
    oa.remove("some");
},1500);
```

However, I would like to know what element got added to the observable array. Is there any way to do this? If I could compare the old array to the new array, then I could determine which item(s) were added or removed. But it seems that by the time the "subscribe" function callback is called, there is no way to access "previous" array values. Is there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

knockout observableArray provides event `arrayChange`.

```
oa.subscribe(function(changes){
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(changes, function(c) {
        console.log(c.status + " value:\"" + c.value + "\" at index:" + c.index);
    });
}, null, 'arrayChange');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/huocp/Vf8RK/3/

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I can't seem to find this mentioned on knockoutjs.com anywhere... ?

Comment: it is only mentioned in knockout release note https://github.com/knockout/knockout/releases

Comment: I guess the reason for no documentation is that this is considered implementation detail for efficient DOM updating (add, remove, not rebuild the whole array of DOM).

Comment: Which is a little disconcerting because it might get changed in a breaking way since it's an internal implementation detail... :/ but I don't think I have a better alternative.

Comment: I think the release note means this is a public interface, and ko also has an extender `trackArrayChanges` for normal `ko.observable` to support this event. http://jsfiddle.net/5cD2m/